# How to avoid removing unwanted records?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

In my application a user can have one favorite list. A favorite list can have many kinds of balls. The problem is that when I try to delete a record of User table (session.delete(user)) it deletes the record of all balls which where added to favorite list of that user

**However,it should just remove the selected record of user, user's favorite list, and favoriteItems of that favorite list, NOT any record from ball table**

**Relationships**

```
Each User must have only one FavoritesList
Each FavoritesList may have zero to many FavoriteItems
Each FavoriteItems must have only one ball 
Each ball can be belong to zero to many FavoriteItems
```

**Classes**

```
@Entity
public class User{
   ....
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   protected FavoritesList favoritesList;

   public User{
     ...
     this.favoritesList = new FavoritesList();
   }

   ....
}

@Entity    
public class FavoritesList {

   ...
   @OneToMany
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   private List<FavoriteItems> items;


   public FavoritesList(){
     this.items = new ArrayList();
   }
   ...
}

@Entity
public class FavoriteItems {
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   private Ball ball;

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for sure you have other lists that keep the balls as there is no cascade defined for @ManyToOne over Ball.

Answer (score 1):

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

this should be the problem, if you are "cascade all", everything : "save, delete, update, evict, lock, replicate, merge, persist" is cascaded to all object related to this one.

I havent used hibernate or jpa for some time, so I cant remember what EXACTLY you need, but this should help choose, what you want or what you dont want to cascade : [hibernate javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html)

Comment: but as I've explained I need it to remove the favoritelist and favoriteitems perhaps if I take out that cascade it wont delete them.